# Load a specific row as default item in combobox

Tags: c#, ms-access, combobox

I fill combo-box with a data from database Access but my question is how can I put a specific row in database filled as a Default item in combo-box with C#?

```
gerant remplirlistgerant = new gerant();
foreach (gerant ligne in remplirlistgerant.getinfogerant())
{
   cmbgerant.Items.Add(ligne.CIN_GERANT + " - " + ligne.NOM_GERANT + " - " + ligne.PRENOM_GERANT);
}
```

Comment: set cmbgerant.SelectedItem = {your specific item}

Comment: it is not worked because  in database access the filling begin with the last row and if i select the row 4 as dafault item and it contain for exemple this line "4-abcd", after add other rows if make other row as default item.for example "8-klmn"......etc?

Comment: you should set selected item after filling whole combobox. Pre-save it during foreach and then select after foreach.

Comment: but the combobox is empty and it fill from database how can i make that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I know yours,

Example `if ligne.CIN_GERANT = "aaa"` the current row will be selected.

```
    gerant remplirlistgerant = new gerant();
    foreach (gerant ligne in remplirlistgerant.getinfogerant())
    {
       cmbgerant.Items.Add(ligne.CIN_GERANT + " - " + ligne.NOM_GERANT + " - " + ligne.PRENOM_GERANT);
       // Example if ligne.CIN_GERANT = "aaa" then select this row.
       if (ligne.CIN_GERANT == "aaa"  )
       {
            cmbgerant.SelectedIndex = cmbgerant.Items.Count - 1;// Item just added
       } 
    }
```

Comment: thank you it 's a good idea  but i don't understand  why you set -1?

Comment: because index from 0 to Items.Count - 1. example if you added two rows, you want select row 2, index of row 2 is 1.